# How to set the default values in a constructor to be the values inherited from a superclass?

Tags: python, inheritance, instance-variables

I am developing a small game, and I have a class called `CardOnBattle` that inherits the class `CardOnHand`. `CardOnHand` has several parameters, the ones I need in this problem are inherited from a class called `Card` and they are: `power` and `damage`.

`CardOnBattle` is initialized with a couple of extra parameters: `power_after_modifiers`, `damage_after_modifiers`, and `attack_after_modifiers`. Now what I want to do is set the default values of `power_after_modifiers` and `damage_after_modifiers` to the parameters `power` and `damage` inherited from `Card`, respectively.

How do I do that?

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, power, damage, stars, level, name, ability, 
                 clan):
        if is_valid_power(power):
            self.power = power
        else:
            self.power = 0
        if is_valid_damage(damage):
            self.damage = damage
        else:
            self.damage = 0
        if is_valid_stars(stars):
            self.stars = stars
        else:
            self.stars = 0
        if is_valid_level(level):
            self.level = level
        else:
            self.level = 0
        self.name = name
        self.ability = ability
        self.clan = clan


class CardOnHand(Card):
    def __init__(self, bonus=None, has_been_used=False):
        self.bonus=bonus
        self.has_been_used=has_been_used


class CardOnBattle(CardOnHand):
    def __init__(self, attack_after_modifiers, 
power_after_modifiers, damage_after_modifiers):
        self.power_after_modifiers = power_after_modifiers
        self.damage_after_modifiers = damage_after_modifiers
        self.attack_after_modifiers = attack_after_modifiers
```

Comment: You can first call  `__init__` from the parent class, then copy some of the values it sets to other instance variables in the derived class.  But in this case, none of the arguments to `__init__` in `Card` have default values, so where would those values come from?

Comment: I don't think inheritance is really the right metaphor here. Is it true that a CardOnBattle **is a** CardOnHand?

Comment: If you added some _class_ attributes to the `Card` class definition, like `default_power = 0`, you can reference it or them inside the class or a subclass method via `self.default_power` and outside them via `Card.default_power`